# Hazelcast incompatible with old version

Tags: hazelcast

I'm upgrade the Hazelcast library from 4.x to the latest 5.3.x version
However from my observer the property `hazelcast.phone.home.enabled` not allow, but it's still
valid in [the document](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.3/system-properties)

Anyone has experience why does this happened please share

Thank you

Here is exception
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a hazelcast.yaml as below. This is just an example to show how to use properties

```
hazelcast:
  properties:
    hazelcast.phone.home.enabled : false
  network:
    join:
      multicast:
        enabled: true
    rest-api:
      enabled: true
```

Then start the member. I am using Hazelcast version 5.3.0

```
HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
Config configc = hazelcastInstance1.getConfig();
String property = config.getProperty("hazelcast.phone.home.enabled");
```

You will see that it is using the value in the yaml file

Comment: great, I think this yaml is good for setup hazelcast properties, Thank you